# Glyph of Iconfont does not appear in browser

Tags: css, icons, typography

I created an iconfont with inkscape, following this tutorial: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont/

It works well, but one of my glyphs does not show up on the website. I can write that glyph in any program, but I can't see it in my browser. The website is: http://www.goldentree.de/wordpress/ You can find the glyphs in the h2 on the left "Article Test X" The missing glyph is the small f, and should look like a facebook icon. You can copy it and the f appears, if you paste it into notepad for example. I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but the problem appears only in the browser, so I guess it does.

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: I can see the f transforming into a facebook f and the A changes to a feather. (Safari 6.0.2)

Comment: Interesting. I tried it in other browsers: IE is the same as firefox (the facebook icon doesnt appear). In Chrome, no icons at all. In Safari every icon looks like expected.

Comment: Im sorry. I couldn't figure out how to embed a font in jsfiddle. I found an example on google, but I dont know, where to uplod the font.

Comment: I didnt manage to build a fiddle, but here is a simple example: http://www.goldentree.de/test/